# Setting opentok react video to use the full height of the enclosing div

Tags: css, reactjs, opentok

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-react in my application and creating a publisher and subscriber in a div. This is the css:

```
#videos {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    //min-height: 720px;
    //margin-left: auto;
    //margin-right: auto;
}
#subscriber {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#publisher {
    position: absolute;
    width: 360px;
    height: 240px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

The problem is when I pass the subscriber component the props `width 100%` and `height 100%` it doesn't obey, it doesn't do what I expect. I expect it to use the full height and widdth of the div with the #subscriber id selector. However it doesn't. Instead if I pass the props as a px value it works. How can I just make the subscriber video componet fit to the size of the container div based on a percentage?

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

When creating publishers and subscribers, the [Opentok-React](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react/) library assigns the `OTPublisherContainer` and `OTSubscriberContainer` classes to the DOM elements so please use them to style to publisher and subscribers, respectively. You can see this in the library code here:

- [OTPublisher](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react/blob/master/src/OTPublisher.js#L115)
- [OTSubscriber](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react/blob/master/src/OTSubscriber.js#L55)

I've also gone ahead and filed an [issue on the repo](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react/issues/57) to improve documentation on styling.

Comment: So if I create a css class .OTSubscriber with a height param of 100vh would that render the video in a container that took up all the whitespace of the container along the height? Sorry don't have my machine handy to test....